# How to call isActive func before onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
oddEvent = (match, location) => {
    if (!match) {
      return false
    } else {
      this.location = match.url
      return true
    }
  }

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.location === '/home' ? this.setState({isHome: true  })
                              : this.setState({isHome: false })
  }



<ul className="main-header__nav-list">
            {links.map((link, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={i}
                    className="main-header__nav-item">
                  <NavLink to={link.linkTo} 
                           activeClassName="main-header__nav-link--active" 
                           className="main-header__nav-link"
                           onClick={this.handleChange}
                           isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                           {link.text}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
```

Want to hide a component when my NavLink 'Home' is not chosen. oddEvent func gives current location. But  onClick always goes first and then handleChange takes old rote name. How can I call isActive first? or how can I get fresh  route in onClick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'isActive' function is called by react-router. I believe it's not updated properly for you. For this, make sure that your component is wrapped with **withRouter** component, and parent component is not preventing re-render. You can see an example in [official doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) as well.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class MainHeaderWithRouter extends Component {
    render() {
        <ul className="main-header__nav-list">
        {links.map((link, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={i}
                className="main-header__nav-item">
              <NavLink to={link.linkTo} 
                       activeClassName="main-header__nav-link--active" 
                       className="main-header__nav-link"
                       onClick={this.handleChange}
                       isActive={this.oddEvent}>
                       {link.text}
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>  
    }    
}

const MainHeaderWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```